# Launch two kinects with single openni.launch

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is easy to start two kinects separately on two different Terminals with the launch files for two kinects by editing the following
kinect1 launch file

*

*

kinect2 launch file

*

*

I can able to launch two nodes of type openni_node(openni_camera pkg) from single launch file
And i want to do the same with the node of type nodelet(openni_launch pkg)

Spent 2 days with this but failed

Need clear insights on this stuff!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50719/launch-two-kinects-with-single-openni.launch/) by [ros_vino](https://answers.ros.org/users/3811/ros_vino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-12-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-12-18**:
You don't need to edit the args. As the name says they are arguments. You can just pass different args to the same launch file and you will get two different launches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use one launch file which expects arguments that you have mentioned in the question as input. Then u can call the launch file twice with different arguments.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0